# get aws account id with eks on fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

i would like to get my aws account id programmatically when running an application on AWS EKS on Fargate.

On EC2 instances I can simply call `http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document` but I can not on fargate.

Can I get the account id without using `aws sts get-caller-identity`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the task metadata endpoint returns detailed data, including the task arn, which contains the account id.

I don't know if there is a better way of getting this information.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113140/15910427